# Notify button clicked in popup window to main window on wpf

Tags: wpf, notifications, popup

I have two windows ,say window1 and window2(this one should be a pop up) on WPF.

What I want to do is, when a button in popup window(window2) is clicked,
I want to run method in window1.
I can achieve this by passing window1 to windows2, but I think it's not an memory-efficient way.

I have red article about routedCommand, but it's hard to understand.
I'm working on c# and any help is appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Quite often I have a static property for `Current` on my `MainViewModel` (or which ever ViewModel), and I set that property in the constructor for the ViewModel.  Then from anywhere else in the application, I can get a reference to the ViewModel in question.

### On the ViewModel

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Current = this;
    }

    public static MainViewModel Current { get; set; }
```

### Anywhere else in the application:

```
MainViewModel.Current.DoSomething();
```

### Routed Command

Routed commands are typically databound, and thus the command logic depends on which Data Context it is written on.  If Window1's DataContext is MainViewModel, and Window2's DataContext is SecondViewModel, in order to have a button on Window2 execute a command on MainViewModel, you will have to have a reference to that instance of MainViewModel as the DataContext for the button in question.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but isn't it kind of similar that passing window1 to window2 in memory-wise?

Comment: I suppose, but we are talking about a reference to an object, not a whole new object.  References are really just memory addresses.  It is when you instance a new object that you start having to worry about the memory cost.  Now, by passing Window1 to Window2, you will be storing that reference for a while, so there is that.  But in my example, I get a reference to the object I want, do something on it, then when it falls out of scope, the GarbageCollector cleans it up the next time it collects.